# Build Fails : 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found XCODE

Tags: react-native

[image]CalendarManager.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
@interface CalendarManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

Solutions tried:

Disable the parallel builds:

- xCode menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Manage Shemes
- Double click on your application
- Build tab -> clear the tick on Pallelize Build
- Add react as a project dependency
- xCode Project Navigator -> drag React.xcodeproj from Libraries to root tree
- Build Phases Tab -> Target Dependencies -> + -> add React

  `“$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React” with “recursive”` set:

  ```
  $(SRCROOT)/../../React         
  $(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React   
  $(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/Libraries
  ```

Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0"
  },
```

Comment: could you provide the screenshot of an error and project setting in Xcode?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: It started working after some time, can't exactly say how exactly it started working

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue for react version mismatch. You could use react version 16.0.0-alpha.6.

In that case, you can run `sudo npm install -g react@16.0.0-alpha.6`

Or, if you use yarn then try `yarn update react@16.0.0-alpha.6`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `react-native 0.50+` depends on `react@16.0.0+`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, your react version ( 16.0.0) is ok, did you check your link Binary libraries in Build Phases Tab? Did you see "libReact.a" ? If you don't then run `react-native link` after install `react`